# UItableview on second page and want to nevigate in third page how it is possible?

Tags: ios6

I have `UITableview` in second page then I try to navigate into third page but problem is that my code is not working. Here is the code for both AppDelegate.m file and also SecondViewController.m file,
 Plz check the code and give me suggestion what i am doing wrong

**SecondViewController.m file code**

```
 - (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

         ThirdViewController *third = [[ThirdViewControllerr alloc] initWithNibName:     @"ThirdViewControllerr" bundle:nil];

         ForthViewController *forth = [[ForthViewControlle alloc] initWithNibName: @"ForthViewController" bundle:nil];

                   if(indexPath.row==0)
                    {
                         [[self navigationController] pushViewController:third animated:YES];

                     }                    

                    if(indexPath.row==1)
                     {
                       [[self navigationController] pushViewController:forth animated:YES];

                     }
```

In AppDelegate.m file i write the code for Secondviewcontroller in witch using UITableview, also i have initialized the UINavigationController inside AppDelegate.m file.If anyone have idea reply me as soon as possible,
without use UINavigationController inside AppDelegate.m file its possible  for UItableview Navigation

**AppsDelegate.m file**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[MobileViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"MobileViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;


        self.window1=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
      self.viewController1=[[HealthCalculatorsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HealthCalculatorsViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_viewController1];
        self.window1.rootViewController=nav1;
       [self.window1 makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
        }
```

Please guide me.
  Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: hii i am adding my code... can u check ?

Comment: did u initialize the uinavigationcontroller?

Comment: Is your navigation controller initialised in appdelgate or any of your view controller ?

Comment: pls post the navigation controller initialization code

Comment: initialised  navigationcontroller in Appdelegate.m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your Appdelegate.h

```
UINavigationController * navController;
```

and this in your Appdelegate.m

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        FirstViewController * viewPhone =[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewPhone];
    }
    else
    {
        FirstViewControllerController * viewPad =[[FirstViewControllerController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewPad];
    }
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;
```

on your button click

```
- (IBAction)Btn_Pressed:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController * second=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)    
        second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];    
    else        
        second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:lagrangae animated:YES];

}
```

if you dont want navigation bar just hide it by

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: can u give me in detail how can i do ?

Comment: show your view controller which contains button as your rootview of navigation and project root view as navigation controller ,on button click push the controller of table view (if u don't want navigation bar make it hidden) then on cell click just push another view controller(detailsviewcontroller).